# Getting the value from textfield to Label in Tableview

Tags: uitableview, ios5, xcode4.2, uitextfield

i am working in an app in whicjh i have tableview which contains the Textfield and Label in it. Now What i want is when i  enter the text in the textfield  that has score it should calculate something and give me the result  percentage in the tableview label for that cell .
Heres how i  created the tetfield and label in cellForRowAtIndexpath.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

lblpercent = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(395, 5, 270, 30)]; 
UITextField *txtscore = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:  CGRectMake(306,5,100,30)];

txtscore.delegate  =  self;
txtscore.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
[txtscore addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDone:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
lblpercent.text = per;
 }
```

And for caqlculation i use the following code

```
-(void) textFieldDone: (id) sender
{


       UITextField *field = sender;
            NSLog(@"%d",i);
        NSString *total =  field.text;
        int tot = [total intValue];
        NSLog(@"The text is  %d", tot);
         per = [[NSString alloc] init];
        if (tot == 90) {
            percent=90;

        }
 per = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",percent];  
   }
```

how can in solve this ?

Comment: Solve what? We need a problem first before we can solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a nice idea that I surely would have never tried if not for your question so thank you ;)

If you don't need any other delegate methods for the textfield other that setting the label you could solve your problem this way.

Create a category on UILabel

```
@interface UILabel (CopyTextField) <UITextFieldDelegate>
@end


@implementation UILabel (CopyTextField)
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // do whatever you want with your textfield's text and set self.text to the value
    self.text = textField.text; // here I'm just copying the text as it is
}
```

@end

On the other hand you need to set your label as the textField's delegate (import UILabel+CopyTextField.h)

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UILabel *lblpercent = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(395, 5, 270, 30)]; 
    UITextField *txtscore = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(306,5,100,30)];

    txtscore.delegate  =  lblpercent;
    txtscore.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i have tried the code and it works the way i want ,can i do it the same way to find the grade because i  need to find the grade based on lblPercent  which is a label on the same row.

Comment: using this solution you can only have one delegate for your textfield, if you need multiple objects to be change when your textField's value is changed then you should have these objects referenced (propertys  for instance) and use your controller as the delegate. Then in the -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField implementation you need to make all the changes you need.